# Split total into 5 different numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Ok what i'm wanting to do is split a number (`$row['count']`) into 5, this is easy enough if you want equal numbers:

```
$sum  = ($row['count'] / 5);
$fsum = floor($sum);
```

**but** I want each number to be different and still add up to total ie `$row['count']` how can this be achieved?

**Update:**

If this helps its to be used to update 5 rows in a database:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM foo";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $sum  = ($row['count'] / 5);
    $fsum = floor($sum);
    $id   = $row['id'];

    $update = "UPDATE foo SET foo1='$fsum', foo2='$fsum', foo3='$fsum', foo4='$fsum', foo5='$fsum' WHERE id='$id'";

    mysql_query($update);

    }// while
```

so ideally the `$update` query would be something like:

```
$update = "UPDATE foo SET foo1='$fsum1', foo2='$fsum2', foo3='$fsum3', foo4='$fsum4', foo5='$fsum5' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: How do you want them to be different ? If you can answer that you most probably can code it.

Comment: Do they all have to be positive integers? If the number is less than 15 (1+2+3+4+5) this is impossible (unless you allow 0 as a component number, in which case the minimum is 0+1+2+3+4=10)

Comment: @Alexandre - Any 5 random numbers that add up to total.

Comment: @AnnaRiekic 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + (number - 10)

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and number and remove it from number (do this 4 times), the left over is the 5th.

Comment: @Waygood But they all have to be different, that will produce 4 the same.

Comment: random number generates 4 times, not the same number

Comment: @Waygood - you'd also need a check that the leftover number isn't one of the four randmly generated ones.

Comment: @Waygood - you could also generate 4 different, random, _negative_ numbers; then you can be sure that your fifth number won't match any. That does even meet the specification, too.

Comment: Negative comments don't help. I have already apologised for missing the __different__ requirement

Comment: @Waygood - that wasn't intended as a negative comment. I was attempting to be humorous, and I apologise if I didn't convey that.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @truth - I know I've been told about this before, but the usage for this is not for a live site but simply to update a database, though admittedly I should use the upto date coding what ever code I am writing.

Comment: @AnnaRiekic: Doesn't matter. I use PDO for my personal projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take:

```
function randomize($sum, $parts) {
    $part_no = count($parts);
    $continnue_counter = 0;

    while (count(array_unique($parts)) != $part_no) {
        $changing = array_rand($parts, 2);
        if (($parts[$changing[0]] - 1) == 0 || ($parts[$changing[1]] - 1) == 0) { // don't let them go under 1
            ++$continnue_counter;

            // sometime one element get everything and others even out on 1
            // just throw away everything you got so far and start over
            if ($continnue_counter > 10) {
                $parts = setup($sum, $part_no);
                $continnue_counter = 0;
            }
            continue;
        }
        $continnue_counter = 0;

        $signum   = mt_rand(0, 100) % 2 ? 1 : -1;
        $delta    = $signum * mt_rand(1, min($parts[$changing[0]] - 1, $parts[$changing[1]] - 1)); // -1 to make sure they don't go under 0
        $parts[$changing[0]] += $delta;
        $parts[$changing[1]] -= $delta;
    }
    return $parts;
}

function setup($sum, $part_no) {
    $parts = array_fill(0, $part_no, (int)($sum / $part_no));

    // acount for the reminder of (int) cast
    $reminder = $sum - array_sum($parts);
    while ($reminder) {
        $parts[array_rand($parts)] += 1;
        --$reminder;
    }

    return $parts;
}

$part_no = 5;
$sum = 42;

$parts = randomize($sum, setup($sum, $part_no));

var_export($parts);
print array_sum($parts)
```

#### Update:

I've added a version that introduces a little more entropy.

#### Update2:

The more random one had a tendency to decrement everything to 1 except one part, added an explicit detection to deal with this. Still the algorithm behind it has unknown termination time.

Comment: The original seems to be doing the trick, but will wait till update query is done before marking as answer, thank you complex857!

Comment: Oh, i've updated again, forgot to use the `$signum` (more entropy). I would strongly recommend to use it with the second one's `$continnue_counter` emergency break, random numbers can be well... whimsical (-:

Comment: Thanks again complex857, current code (update 2) working better, marked as answer.